# Firefox не даёт получить координаты элементов в svg

Tags: javascript, svg, firefox

При использовании метода `getBoundingClientRect()` для элементов svg всегда возвращает координаты самого холста, а не элемента. И метод `getBBox()` вызывается только для svg, а при попытке вызова у элемента, возвращает такую ошибку:

> [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"
>   location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code ::  :: line 1"
>   data: no]

В остальных браузерах всё отрабатывает корректно, может в фф есть какой-то атрибут влияющий на это?

Проверялось в версиях 68.0 и 69.0b4 на win10 и в последней версии на маке.

На сколько понял, в фф, все элементы находящиеся в `defs` имеют ширину и высоту 0 и не доступны для вызова `getBBox()`.

```js
var getSvgBounds = document.getElementById('svg').getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('svgBounds');
console.log(getSvgBounds);

var getRectBounds = document.getElementById('clipRect').getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('clipRectBounds');
console.log(getRectBounds);


var getSvgBox = document.getElementById('svg').getBBox();
console.log('svgBox');
console.log(getSvgBox);

var getRectBox = document.getElementById('clipRect').getBBox();
console.log('clipRectBox');
console.log(getRectBox);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/15/200/200" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/491/200/200" width="200" height="200" />

        </pattern>

        <clipPath id="clip">
            <rect id="clipRect" width="50" height="50" rx="25" x="35" y="50" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <rect width="200" height="200" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <rect width="200" height="200" fill="url(#img2)" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Ну если верить докам, то должно работать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: а на других версиях фф проверяли?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev так метод то работает, но возвращает не те значения

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Проверил сейчас в 67.0 и 66.0 - аналогично, думаю в предыдущих версиях тоже

Comment: А можно сниппет с [mcve] в вопрос добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавил

Comment: я думаю это связано с тем, что этот элемент не рендерится, а фф берет значение фактически посчитанные при рендере, берите атрибуты у элемента и пляшите от них